# Floor buggs out as soon as I start walking

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I am Programming a 2D game in Unity and I wanted to ask why the floor keeps bugging out and snaps to the its original position as soon as I press A or D. Heres a [video](https://www.reddit.com/link/13kwl05/video/43kxbv32uk0b1/player).

I tried to make a platform that my character is walking on and I expected the character to walk over it but instead he glides on the plattform(idk how to describe it so its better if you watch the video i linked).

I used this code:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ParralaxBackround : MonoBehaviour {

    [SerializeField] private Vector2 parallaxEffectMultiplier;

    private Transform cameraTransform;
    private Vector3 lastCameraPosition;
    private float textureUnitSizeX;

    private void Start () {
        cameraTransform = Camera.main.transform;
        lastCameraPosition = cameraTransform.position;
        Sprite sprite = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite;
        Texture2D texture = sprite.texture;
        textureUnitSizeX = texture.width / sprite.pixelsPerUnit;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    private void LateUpdate()
    {
        Vector3 deltaMovement = cameraTransform.position - lastCameraPosition;
        transform.position += new Vector3(deltaMovement.x * parallaxEffectMultiplier.x, deltaMovement.y * parallaxEffectMultiplier.y);
        lastCameraPosition = cameraTransform.position;

        if (Mathf.Abs(cameraTransform.position.x - transform.position.x) >= textureUnitSizeX)
        {
            float offsetPositionX = (cameraTransform.position.x - transform.position.x) % textureUnitSizeX;
            transform.position = new Vector3(cameraTransform.position.x + offsetPositionX, transform.position.y);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think the floor should have a Parallax Background script on it, right?

Comment: But what else? If I dont add it, then the plattform will just end at a certain point. The script handles infinite and parralax backround at the same time.

Comment: Does it work if you set the 'parallax effect multiplier' on the floor to zero in both axes? Then I think it shouldn't move with the camera, but still be infinite.